# If $A \subseteq B \cap C$, then $A \subset B$ and $ A \subseteq C.$ Prove that this is False...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I had this question in a test. My logic was that any subset, say $A$, of the intersection between $B$ and $C$ would imply that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and that $A$ is a subset of $C$ since anything in the intersection exists in both sets, when the intersection is not empty.
When the intersection is empty, I figured it still remains true since the empty set is a subset of every set.
I found that this implication is a true statement.
Was my logic incorrect?
My teacher removed it from the test and never gave an explanation as to why, or what the solution was. Just curious to know if I had gotten it right.

Comment: If $A=B=C$ it's clearly not true. Unless you meant to use $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the distinction between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ in the title is intended or is a typo.  If by $\subset$ you mean "is a proper subset of (*and is not equal*)" then Peter's counterexample works.  If you meant both to be "propersubset or equal" then $A\subseteq (B\cap C)\subseteq B$ implies that $A\subseteq B$ is indeed true.  Similarly for $C$.  So, the statement $A\subseteq (B\cap C)\implies A\subseteq B\wedge A\subseteq C$ is true

Comment: That's how it was written on the test.

Comment: What Peter Foreman's comment is focusing on.  That is, focus on your query's title.  Notice that it (apparently) is employing **both** the symbol for "subset" and the symbol for "proper subset".  The key to this problem is the distinction between subset and proper subset.

Comment: that was a typo, I am sorry I fixed I don't know if it is showing as fixed

Comment: A similar but false statement would be that $B\cap C\subseteq A$ implies that $B\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq A$.  If the teacher intended to give a false statement, perhaps the teacher intended to use this one instead.  For a counterexample to that, consider $A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{1,3\}$

Comment: If $A$ is in both $B$ and $C$, then $A$ is in $B$ and $A$ is in $C$.  If I have interpreted the edited title correctly, then the statement that you are being asked to prove as *false* is in fact *true*.

Comment: Thank you every body. This was very helpful. Thank you for taking the time. She probably just had a slip up on the write up. I'm new to proofs and so doubt always creeps in for these problems.